Crash reporting tool which differentiate crash from my SDK and Client App in Android
I have an Android SDK and my clients integrate into their Apps, I have added FirebaseAnalytics and Sentry to detect my SDK crash but I am also getting the clients app crashes. How to filter it out or are there any tool which only capture my SDKs crash and logs

Just a thought that you might be able to use Acra instead
As you could probably configure it to only send reports you are interested in as Acra seems to be more configurable with things like custom report senders, etc.
and then use
alsoReportToAndroidFramework option
To chain to any other Exception handler i.e FirebaseAnalytics
I've not tried this but there was a similar question
